# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 at Power.main(Power.java:7)

Tags: java

```
public class Power {

    public static void main (String[]args){

        int num = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);


        int square = (int) Math.pow(num,2);
        int cube = (int) Math.pow(num ,3);
        int sqrt = (int) Math.sqrt(num);

        System.out.println(num + "squared is" + square);
        System.out.println(num + "Cubed is" + cube);
        System.out.println(num + "The square root of" + sqrt);

    }

}
```

could someone please tell me where I am going wrong? and why I am receiving the following error message in the title

Comment: Are you passing the parameter to the exe? It looks like the "args" array is empty

Answer (score 0):

What's on line 7 ? I suspect you're running the class `Power` without a command line arg, and this line:

```
 int num = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
```

(which tries to read the first command line arg and parse it as an integer) is blowing up

Answer (score 0):

It simply means you are trying to access Array with invalid index (valid index is from 0 to arr.length-1 for arr.length > 0)

In your case `int num = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);` is causing the issue.

You should pass a number from as a command line argument to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

This means that there is no item at args[0], the list is empty. The program is being run with no arguments, and you should check by doing args.length and making sure it's not 0, then possibly printing an error that it requires an argument if not passed one.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using:

```
int num = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
```

You should pass a parameter to the function in the moment you start your application.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main (String[]args){

    if(args.length ==0) { 
      System.out.printf("Please pass command line argument e.g Power 10") ; 
      System.exit(1) ;  
    } 

    int firstArg;
    if (args.length > 0) {
        try {
            firstArg = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.err.println("Argument" + args[0] + " must be an integer.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }   
    int num = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);


    int square = (int) Math.pow(num,2);
    int cube = (int) Math.pow(num ,3);
    int sqrt = (int) Math.sqrt(num);

    System.out.println(num + "squared is" + square);
    System.out.println(num + "Cubed is" + cube);
    System.out.println(num + "The square root of" + sqrt);

}
```

Comment: This is line is causing the issue  
int num = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

Better to validate ,  Please use above code if you want to validate command line argument with your program.